# insertar multiples "rows" en access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

existe alguna forma o manera de hacer esto funcione en access 2016 (simplemente da un error)

```
>     Se ha producido el error '3137' en tiempo de ejecucion: 
>     
>     Falta punto y coma (;) al final de la instruccion SQL.
```

Sintaxis

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO MiTabla (Campo1,Campo2,Campo3) VALUES ('dato0','dato1','dato2') , ('dato3','dato4','dato5');"
```

Answer (score 1):

En vba no es posible. Al menos por lo que he visto en otros foros no de manera sencilla y rápida. Yo normalmente tengo los valores en un array y voy iterando y, a cada fila del array, hago un INSERT INTO. Esto quiere decir que si el array tiene mil filas hago mil INSERT INTO.

Como te digo, en varios foros, si que he leido que hay formas de hacer lo que pides, pero se complica un poco la cosa. Por ejemplo, en la versión inglesa de SO [tienes esta respuesta.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504/is-there-any-way-to-create-multiple-insert-statements-in-a-ms-access-query/65027#65027)